# Cannot find namespace System.IdentityModel.Services

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I'm trying to provide user authentication by implementing `UserNamePasswordValidator`. I have added `Microsoft.IdentityModel` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry` nuget packages.

I'm getting and error when I implement `UserNamePasswordValidator` in my class `UserAuthentication` saying

> The type or namespace name Selectors does not exist in namespace
> `System.IdentityModel` (are you missing some reference).

Why is this failing?

```
public class UserAuthentication : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userName == "test" && password == "test123")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Authentic User");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding the nuget package is not enough (and also in your case, unnecessary), you need to reference the dll in your project. Look for the References list in the solution explorer.

Right click -> Add Reference -> type System.IdentityModel to search box -> select the right dll -> click OK -> Good to go